# UItesting : Click on UIcollectionview then testing it get failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, xcode-ui-testing

I am new at ui-testing. During recording, when I *tap* on *ui-collection view* first object is shown on UI and corresponding to code written in test-example method is:

```
XCUIElement *window = [[app childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeWindow] elementBoundByIndex:0];
    XCUIElement *element2 = [[[[window childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element;
    [element2 tap];
```

And when automating the test-example method, it's *unable to fetch first object of ui-collection view*. please suggest a way to do that. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i just found a way to do that just uncheck accessibility enable in attribute inspector and re run the recording .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recording UITests tends to give you really long and ugly queries. I strongly suggest that you have a look on how to write UITests manually. It's really easy and the queries look much better.

For example: to tap on the first cell of your collection view all you need to do is this (providing that there is only one `UICollectionView` on the current screen):

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)testExample {
    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    [app launch];

    [[app.collectionViews.cells elementBoundByIndex:0] tap];
}
```

**Swift**

```
func testExample() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()

    // tap on the first collection view cell on the current screen
    app.collectionViews.cells.element(boundBy:0).tap()
}
```

Comment: can you tell me more about how to focus your keyboard? Because when i am testing on ui-text field there is error saying that                                               Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus. thanks for your time.

Comment: Before you can type text into an UITextField you have to tap() it.

Comment: i am tap on that but i guess when playing the recorded code it doesn't know where to tap so it tap on other place rather than that specific position so   it give these error :- Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus. Element:

Comment: You should really try to write the tests manually. Have a look at the answer to this question for guidance on how to access a text field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658482/how-to-test-uitextfield-in-xcode-ui-testing-when-the-text-field-is-empty