# How to UI test UICollectionViewCell didSelect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have a `UIViewController` that has a child `UIViewController`, this child holds a `UICollectionView` and inside this collectionView I need to simulate  a [didSelect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview) method or in other words, a user tapped on a `UICollectionViewCell`.

I tried to record and got something like this:

```
app.buttons["Tap here"].tap()
```

Which didn't work at all when I tried to run the test again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try replacing 'buttons' with 'cells' in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look deeper into writing UI Test without recording.
Recording is fine for the basic UI's but if you use CollectionViews and TableViews, these tests tend to get even more fragile if you use the record function.
Have a look into this answer to get started: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46711287/1501847)

Comment: Thanks for the tip zero3nna, but I didn't manage to find the element anyway.
I ran: 

        let allAny = app.descendants(matching: .any)
        print(allAny.debugDescription)

And saw a lot of "Other" elements without labels or identifiers. Is there something I should do in the app itself to allow it be visible for the testing code?

Comment: Is the element query for `app.collectionViews.count` = 0?

Comment: Yep, no collectionViews. Mostly "other". Maybe I need something in the app itself that I am missing?

Comment: Maybe you need to reduce the `AccessibilityElement`'s in `app`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42038145/1501847